# Page to show Modified Date of file in File Library

Tags: publishing-page

I have an Excel file that is in a file library. I'd like to have a page that shows when that Excel file was last modified.

Anybody know of a piece of code that will show "Date Modified" of an Excel file in a file library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code on page or user control.

```
public DateTime GetLastModifedForFile()
{ 

 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
 {
  using (SPSite siteColl = new SPSite("http://spsite"))
  {
   using (SPWeb web = siteColl.OpenWeb())
   {

     SPFile spfile = web.GetFile("Source_Folder_Name/Source_File");
     if (spfile.Exists)
     {
        return spfile.TimeLastModified;
     }

   } 
  }
 });

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm new to Sharepoint coding... where do I put this on my page? (meaning: how do I incorporate this?)

Comment: This link can help you to start with : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330921.aspx

Comment: What I ended up doing was inserting a Data View on my page. That allowed me to get what I needed. Thank you, Amit, for sending me down the right road.

Comment: Dataview will work only if user have permission on library.If not (like you mentioned in your coment in another answer), you have to use  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Answer (score 2):

The Modified column displays this automatically.  Be sure to include the column in your view.

Comment: I see the Modified date when **I** look at the File Library. I want that date to appear on a page in the site for those that don't have access to look at the 'raw' file library.

Comment: How are you exposing the library to end users?  Are you putting a web part on the publishing page? If so, include the modified date in that view.

Comment: I just have an aspx page with some HTML links to the file where they can download the file.

Comment: Are you dynamically generating that content?  The easiest approach is to add a web part into a web part zone onto your publishing page and expose the desired metadata.  Other options include writing some javascript/jQuery to fetch the information using a handy tool called SPServices, http://spservices.codeplex.com.

Comment: The Excel file is uploaded once every two weeks. It's always called the same thing ("Deposit.xls"). When the user hits the site page, there's a link there that allows them to download the file. 
I'll look at that SPServices tool. I've seen that listed before as helping in certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by using document webpart, and modifying the current view to show only name and modified and filtered it with the file name, disable tool bar etc as per your need. 
Amit's solution is the best one, but I had to use this because inside our company environment we are not allowed to add any scripts or can we use share-point designer.